# Interpretation of Greek characters by FOP

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Can you please help me interpret the Greek Characters with HTML display as HTML= & #8062; and Hex value 01F7E

Details of these characters can be found on the below URL

http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/index.php?page=01&subpage=F&hilite=01F7E

When I run this character in Apache FOP, they give me an ArrayIndexOut of Bounds Exception

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
  at org.apache.fop.text.linebreak.LineBreakUtils.getLineBreakPairProperty(LineBreakUtils.java:668)
  at org.apache.fop.text.linebreak.LineBreakStatus.nextChar(LineBreakStatus.java:117)

When I looked into the FOP Code, I was unable to understand the need for lineBreakProperties[][] Array in LineBreakUtils.java.

I also noticed that FOP fails for all the Greek characters mentioned on the above page which are non-displayable with the similar error.

What are these special characters ?
Why is their no display for these characters are these Line Breaks or TAB’s ?
Has anyone solved a similar issue with FOP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Answer from Apache***

At first glance, this seems like a minor oversight in the implementation of Unicode linebreaking in FOP. This does not take into account the possibility that a given codepoint is not assigned a 'class' in linebreaking context. (=
U+1F7E does not appear in the file
http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/LineBreak.txt, which is used as a basis to generate those arrays in LineBreakUtils.java)

On the other hand, one could obviously raise the question why you so desperately need to have an unassigned codepoint in your output. Are you absolutely sure you need this? If yes, then can you elaborate on the exact reason? (i.e. What exactly is this unassigned codepoint used for?)

The most straightforward 'fix' seems to be roughly as follows:

## Index: src/java/org/apache/fop/text/linebreak/LineBreakStatus.java

--- src/java/org/apache/fop/text/linebreak/LineBreakStatus.java    (revision
1054383)
+++ src/java/org/apache/fop/text/linebreak/LineBreakStatus.java    (working
copy)
@@ -87,6 +87,7 @@

```
     /* Initial conversions */
     switch (currentClass) {
```

+            case 0: // Unassigned codepoint: consider as AL?
             case LineBreakUtils.LINE_BREAK_PROPERTY_AI:
             case LineBreakUtils.LINE_BREAK_PROPERTY_SG:
             case LineBreakUtils.LINE_BREAK_PROPERTY_XX:

What this does, is assign the class 'AL' or 'Alphabetic' to any codepoint that has not been assigned a class by Unicode. This means it will be treated as a regular letter.
Now, the reason why I am asking the question whether you are sure you know what you're doing, is that this may turn out to be undesirable. Perhaps the character in question needs to be treated as a space rather than a letter.
Unicode does not define U+1F7E other than as a 'reserved' character, so it makes sense that Unicode cannot say what should happen with this character in the context of linebreaking...

That said, it is also wrong of FOP to crash in this case, so the bug is definitely genuine.

Answer (score 0):

The U+1F7E code point is part of the Greek Extended Unicode block. But it is does not represent any actual character; it is a reserved but unassigned code point. Here is the chart from Unicode 6.0: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F00.pdf.

So the errors you are getting are perhaps not so surprising.

Comment: Hi Mzjn, consider a case that i am getting these in a datastream and i am converting that stream to PDF every 2 mins, what should I do show them as # or not show them at all. Just asking from your experience.

Comment: @Geek, I don't really have any experience with processing datastreams into PDF. Do you have any control over the datastream? Why does it contain non-existent "characters"? 

If you can identify unassigned code points, then you might be able to display them as "#", or not at all. Perhaps you can use [Character.isLetter()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

But that's just me guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a FO file that included the following `<fo:block>` through both FOP 0.95 and FOP 1.0:

```
<fo:block>Unassigned code point: &#x1F7E;</fo:block>
```

I did get the same java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that you are seeing.

When using an adjacent "real" character, there was no error:

```
<fo:block>Assigned code point: &#x1F7D;</fo:block>
```

So it seems like you have to ensure that your datastream does not contain non-characters like U+1F7E.

Comment: The error comes because of the lineBreakUtil class in FOP. For every non visible charachter the array returns a value 0 and than FOP tries to access the indiex Array[0-1] and hence the Array Indiex out of bounds exception. I see that there is a bug raised on FOP for this, FOP should handle the 0-1 cases.